# Expo thows error that I need to run pod install

Tags: android, mongodb, react-native, expo, realm

I get an error message when trying to " import Realm from "realm" "
The error message:

> Error: Missing Realm constructor. Did you run "pod install"? Please
> see
> https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#missing-realm-constructor
> for troubleshooting

Running on Android 13 SDK (latest from Android Studio) through the command "expo start". I get the error, but I cant fix it since im not on Mac, and it also shouldnt require pods, since Im also running it on Android and not iOS. (iOS throws the same error).

The error message also refers to a non-existing website which is very helpful :) Thank you MongoDB team...

Expo SDK v. 44.0.0
realm v. 10.17.0 (latest?)

My goal is to make an offline-first database application and its not going so well...

Comment: Ive rewritten the app to not use Expo, and it works fine.